# Retrieve element with click event from a table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table, where each line has a column with an image and a textarea field where it is to describe the image. how do I click the image to retrieve the textarea content?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.image', function(e) {
    // logic here
   
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <img class="image" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/female1-512.png" width="100">
      </td>

      <td>
        <textarea class="text"> observation 1 </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <img class="image" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/female1-512.png" width="100">
      </td>

      <td>
        <textarea class="text"> observation 2 </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is presumptive of your current structure showing a two column table with the image in the first column and the textarea in the second column.  In essence the solution presumes that since the image is in the first column, it will find the `<td>` in column 2 containing the `<textarea>` and get text `val()` content from that.  HTH.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.image', function(e) {
    // logic here
    var text = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('textarea').val();
    console.log(text);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <img class="image" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/female1-512.png" width="100">
      </td>

      <td>
        <textarea class="text"> observation 1 </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <img class="image" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/female1-512.png" width="100">
      </td>

      <td>
        <textarea class="text"> observation 2 </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: @Bruno If the structure remains consistent then yes, it will work in a dynamic context.  Basically if you maintain a 2 column table with the image and textarea (regardless of how many rows), then it will work in all situations, otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .parent() method followed by .children() method to go up and then go towards the textarea if it is a fixed structure